# Change background-image css resulting adding additional div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, laravel-blade

I'm creating a template in blade.php based on an original HTML template. When I try to change the URL of the background image, instead of changing it, it creates an additional div to the style, like 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nn6i.jpg), which results in other templated background attributes such as `position` or `size` being ignored. How can I solve this?

```
<div data-bs-parallax-bg="true" id="pic_promo_1" style="background-image: url(#); height: 500px; background-position: center; background-size: cover;"></div>
```

```js
if ($('#pic_promo_1').length) {
  $('#pic_promo_1').css('background-image', 'url({{asset("/images/products/$products->pic_promo_1")}})')
}
```

Comment: Nothing in the code you've shown will create a new div. There must be another section of your code which is causing this problem.

Comment: I dont get it, that should be the only line the script modified. Also i noticed the added style has it own background attribute such as transparent and overflow. Shouldn't the sricpt only modify the value of the url?

Answer (score 0):

Write like this

```
if ($('#pic_promo_1').length) {   
  var imageUrl = "/examples/images/sky.jpg";
  $("#pic_promo_1").css("background-image", "url(" + imageUrl + ")");
}
```

Comment: The result is still the same